# Event handling ideas

Tags: java, event-handling, event-delegation

I have two classes extended from JPanels and both the panels have buttons which when clicked perform a common activity. What will be the best way to achieve this? Does event delegation enter here? like passing the control to handler on another class? (I have assumed thats what delegation is, if I am not wrong)(If delegation is suitable pls provide some good study resource). I have also thought of having a common static method and each classes actionPerformed might call that!! Or is there any other better way?

Comment: I've got to throw in the usual comment that it is rarely a good idea to extend `JPanel` (or `JFrame` or `Thread`). Prefer composition.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using an [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) object, if you have two or more components which perform the same function when acted upon.

Take a look at the [Tutorial | How to Use Actions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more information.

Comment: Read the link you provided. Good one :) will mark as answer after reading others' answers as well :)

Comment: Can you explain whether static method will also be good comparatively?